# Responsable « du/de la », « de » ou « pour » quelque chose ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, articles

Je suis en train d'écrire mon CV et je voudrais connaitre quelques petits détails sur le mot « responsable ».

Comment on peut l'utiliser ? Je veux décrire les responsabilités que j'avais pendant mon stage. Alors dois-je écrire *du* (ou au féminin *de la*) :

> Responsable du développement du logiciel
>   Responsable de la maintenance

ou bien *de* :

> Responsable de développement du logiciel

ou avec *pour* ?

> Responsable pour le développement du logiciel

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment lié à la question mais on écrit en général « développement logiciel » (*logiciel* est ici l'adjectif), à moins que l'on ne parle d'un logiciel bien défini.

Comment: Oui, je parle d'un logiciel spécifique d'un robot aussi spécifique. Alors je crois je vais utiliser «du/de la».

Answer (score 6):

*Responsable du développement* et *Responsable de la maintenance* sont couramment utilisés.