# Peut-on dire "responsable pour"?

Tags: usage, prépositions

J'ai remarqué que la plupart du temps, l'adjectif *responsable* est suivi par la préposition *de*. Y a-t-il des situations où l'on peut l'utiliser avec la préposition *pour* ? Par exemple:

> Je suis responsable pour la fête demain.

ou

> Je suis responsable pour organiser la fête demain.

Je pense que ma question est plus générale que celle montrée par Laure, car elle comprend le cas "responsable + infinitif" aussi bien que d'autres cas possibles, tandis que cette question-là ne concerne qu'un cas spécifique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsable « du/de la », « de » ou « pour » quelque chose ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/responsable-du-de-la-de-ou-pour-quelque-chose)

Comment: Je suis en charge d'organiser la fête demain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On est **responsable de** quelque chose, que ce quelque chose soit exprimé par un nom ou par un infinitif. À noter que l'emploi du nom est beaucoup plus fréquent.

> Je suis responsable de l'organisation de la fête.
>   Je suis responsable d'organiser la fête.

On peut dans ces cas là rencontrer « responsable pour » mais c'est considéré comme un anglicisme (voir par exemple [Termium plus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_r&page=9h8ifww0o8kg.html)). Ce cas n'est même pas signalé dans [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/responsable).

---

**Responsable pour** s'emploie dans certains cas quand la responsabilité s'exerce sur une personne.

- > Je suis responsable de mes enfants.

  Signifie que ma responsabilité est de faire que mes enfants soient élevés et éduqués correctement.
- > Je suis responsable pour mes enfants.

  Signifie que je suis responsable des actions commises par mes enfants.  S'ils commettent des délits c'est à moi de les assumer financièrement et/ou pénalement. *Pour* exprime l'endossement d'une responsabilité, ça signifie « à leur place ».

Comment: Détail supplémentaire : En anglais "be responsible for" peut signifier ou "être celui qui s'occupe de" ou "être celui qui a fait, qui a perpétré". Le terme français présente-il le même choix ? Si oui, est-ce que la préposition ou quelque chose d'autre dans le comportement de la phrase révèle le sens voulu ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak En français je dirais aussi bien « je suis responsable de l'accident » que « je suis responsable de la logistique de l'entreprise. ».

Comment: Ok. Merci pour... euh, de la précision. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak l'un ou l'autre... (question déjà posée sur FL). https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6437/358

Comment: Hm, j'aurais deviné incorrectement un usage dérivé de l'anglais, comme *responsable pour*, quoique beaucoup plus courant. Je me suis trompé, il semble être entièrement français à l'origine. Merci.